# Organising mp3 files, autotagging

Tags: tags, automation, mp3, directory

I'm paying high price for not organising my mp3 files on regular basis.
There are three big steps I need to take and without automation they are a nightmare.

1 . Organise folders (so far I moved all mp3 folders to one location):

- G:/Music/New Folder/artist/ (1000 files here)
- G:/Documents/Music/mp3/ (1000 files here)
- G:/New Folder/Music/new/ (1000 files here)
- and so on, you got the idea

So, what I'm looking for is a way I can move all the mp3 files from folders/subfolders/ to one G:/Sorted Music folder.

2 . Take the

- filename "01 - ABBA - Waterloo", Title: "Waterloo", Artist: "Unknown" and make it
- filename "ABBA - Waterloo", Title: "Waterloo", Artist: "ABBA", deleting every other attribute/field at the same time ("Album", "Contributing Artist", "Comments" etc.)

3 . Having mp3 files all in one place, and all in the same format, divide them into folders:

- Sorted Music/Artist/ (files here)
- Sorted Music/Artist/ (files here)

For points 2 and 3(especially) I downloaded Mp3tag v2.54. However, because of the "01" in the filename, it "misextracts" information from filename to put into tags. And because of "Unknown" for the artist, it won't make the filename right.

Any useful tips will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If your files have a similar name. ANYTHING - BAND - TITLE then this should be no problem. You can use Autoit3 to organize your files and set and get the mp3 tags.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm happy with Mp3tag program. %track% - %artist% - %title% will take care of the bit with putting correct tabs. Point 3 shouldn't be a problem as well, will need to see whether I can choose attributes to be deleted. Still, I don't have many ideas for point 1.